# Missing Data in the dataframe when I use pandas concat

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple code below to grab Financial information from Yahoo Finance.

In the loop shown below, at the end of the loop, I try to concat the Pandas Dataframe together.

When I try to print output, there are easily some outputs missing.  The 2nd item on the list is "VOO" and I should be getting data there.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Please help.  Thanks.

---

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

urls=[
'AAPL',
'voo',
'msft'
    ]

tickerArray2 = pd.DataFrame()

for url in urls:
    tickerTag = yf.Ticker(url)
    tickerArray = tickerTag.actions
    tickerArray['ticker'] = url
    pdArray = pd.DataFrame(tickerArray)
    tickerArray2 = pd.concat([tickerArray2,tickerArray])

print(tickerArray2)
```

---

Output should look like this: 
(for some reason, I'm missing a bunch of data, esp the one with VOO)

```
            Dividends  Stock Splits ticker
Date                                      
1987-05-11    0.00214           0.0   AAPL
1987-06-16    0.00000           2.0   AAPL
1987-08-10    0.00214           0.0   AAPL
...               ...           ...    ...
2012-02-14    0.20000           0.0   VOO
2012-05-15    0.20000           0.0   VOO
2012-08-14    0.20000           0.0   VOO
...               ...           ...    ...
2012-02-14    0.20000           0.0   msft
2012-05-15    0.20000           0.0   msft
2012-08-14    0.20000           0.0   msft
```

Comment: Your code works fine with me.

Comment: That's so strange.  When I run it, there's for sure data missing on my end.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What does `tickerArray2['ticker'].unique()` return?

Comment: inside the loop, it returns: 
['AAPL']
['AAPL' 'voo']
['AAPL' 'voo' 'msft']
outside the loop, it returns: 
['AAPL' 'voo' 'msft']

Comment: The outside the loop has all the data- I do not understand your question! :((

Comment: I'm sorry... :-(  This is an unusual case.  I just ran the codes again and I'm still missing the item in the middle of the list.  Is it possible that the dataframe is setting up its own index and not allowing data to concat?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are passing the wrong object into the concat.  I would change the concat line to:

```
tickerArray2 = pd.concat([tickerArray2,pdArray])
```